# AOSP repositories required to build a package

Tags: makefile, android-source

I am trying to modify and build a system app from aosp (aosp keyboard) and then distribute it seperately. Since it uses the aosp build system, the "correct" way to build such app is to download full aosp (100+ GB). Is there any list of packages (aosp repositories) that are enought to build an app? Is there any other reliable way?

PS: I am not very experienced with build systems. I tryied [this](http://wiresareobsolete.com/2016/03/platform-apps-in-android-studio/) guide to convert aosp apps into gradle, but the project structure doesn't really match.

Answer (score 0):

If you need smaller and easy build env try use sources from aosp to implement custom keyboard and install it as addition input method instead of replacing system app

Comment: I think I was not cleat enought. I am not building whole android. I am trying to build the keyboard and then distribute it seperately with some modifications.

Comment: it will not work for you.
1. "distribute it seperately" - how are you going to install it? you cannot replace/update app on system partition if it is not your buld (you have to sign with system cert for this, and you do not have this certs for all possible devices)

2. You may change package name for app. As result there will be 2 keyboard on device. But it is similar to creating custom keyboard (input method) as I described in first comment.

Comment: If you really need use sources from aosp - build aosp first (as described on sources.android.com) than modify keyboard and build your changes with mmm command (in its output find path to apk). 
also "aosp" is not 250Gb. My copy is about 100Gb

repo sync -c --no-clone-bundle -j4

Comment: 100Gb still means using all of my family's internet connections for a day or two. I want to know **if** there is some way of doing this efficently. I am currently building the sources of the app using gradle but it does some weird things with JNI, so I an trying to do it in more "correct" way.

Comment: use aosp is incorrect approach for your task. Just find any sample for custom android keyboard and create your own keyboard on top of it. Just enter "android keyboard" in github search. e.g. https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/AnySoftKeyboard

Comment: That is what I wanted to do... just with AOSP keyboard, beacause it looks clean and simple. AnySoftKeyboard was my first try, but there was too much spaghetti code. Finally I managed to achive what I wanted by using gradle. Thanks for your advice.